# Delphi JPG максимальный размер

Tags: delphi, jpeg

Согласно [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)
JPG может быть размером 65535х65535.

```
var
 jpg: TJpegImage;
begin
  jpg := TJpegImage.Create;
   jpg.SetSize(65535,65535);
   jpg.SaveToFile('d:\BigJP.jpg');
  jpg.Free;
end;
```

Выдает ошибку:

> First chance exception at $000007FEFD63A06D. Exception class EInvalidGraphicOperation with message 'Cannot change the size of a JPEG image'. Process Project1.exe (7948)

```
jpg.SetSize(32767,32767);
```

Tакая же ошибка, в Лазарусе лучше, но тоже максимального размера добиться не удалось. Аппаратные возможности ПК позволяют. Вопрос: куда копать?

**UPD1** В лазарусе, данный код работает без вылетов, но на выходе черный прямоугольник, попробую копать в направлении Лазаруса. Файл успешно создается и открывается в редакторах.

```
 bmp:=TBitMap.Create;
 bmp.PixelFormat:=pf24bit;
 bmp.Width:=359*256;
 bmp.Height:=61*256;
 png:=TPortableNetworkGraphic.Create;  
 // Рисую на bmp
 png.Assign(bmp);
 png.SaveToFile('g:\BIGpng.png');
```

Comment: Копайте в сторону libjpeg-turbo и jpeg_write_scanlines. Пример можно подсмотреть вот тут: [LibJpegWrite.pas](https://bitbucket.org/sas_team/sas.planet.src/src/6be1f0efa3ff14392c2c61b1d8376ca0b0b98c89/Includes/LibJpeg/LibJpegWrite.pas?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Comment: Посмотрел данные библиотеки, не нашел достаточно документации и примеров, реализовать не смог. Jpg отпал, нужен PNG, файл получается больше 65535х65535

Comment: У PNG точно такой же лимит на размер. Если нужно больше 64k pix, то можете попробовать взять tiff (bigtiff) или jpeg2000.

Comment: jpeg2000 - для Delphi только х86 нашел. Нужна х64 версия.

Answer (score 1):

Копать сюда

```
jpg.SetSize(65535,65535);

procedure TGraphic.SetSize(AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  Width := AWidth;
  Height := AHeight;
end;

procedure TJPEGImage.SetWidth(Value: Integer);
begin
  InvalidOperation(SChangeJPGSize);
end;

procedure TJPEGImage.SetHeight(Value: Integer);
begin
  InvalidOperation(SChangeJPGSize);
end;
```

Таким образом, размер JPEG изменить невозможно. Да и не нужно.

Вам нужно создать нужный Вам Bitmap и его уже сжать в JPEG

```
var
  bmp: TBitmap;
  jpg: TJpegImage;
begin
  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    bmp.SetSize(65535, 65535);
    jpg := TJpegImage.Create;
    try
      jpg.Assign(bmp);
      jpg.SaveToFile('d:\BigJP.jpg');
    finally
      jpg.Free;
    end;
  finally
    bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Но у меня на такую операцию не хватило памяти

Comment: bmp.SetSize(65535, 65535); Ошибка "Параметр задан не верно" bmp.SetSize(32767, 32767); Out of system resources, хотя памяти полно.

Comment: @Demi Тут другая память используется. Ресурсы GDI заканчиваются. Какую Вы задачу решаете?

Comment: Нужно склеить кучу мелких рисунков в один. Сейчас клею в большие какие получаются, а уже большие куски клею в PS, хотелось бы сразу. Раз PS может, значит как то можно это сделать.

Comment: @Demi тогда Вам нужно перейти на работу непосредственно, с памятью и API функциями. [Здесь](http://www.sql.ru/forum/1217699/sozdanie-bitmap) есть про создание битмапа из памяти. Как его перегнать в jpeg смотрите сами

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто, предельно просто. Допустим хочется сделать картинку размером 65535 на 65535 и под один пиксель отведем 4 байта (классически). В результате нужно 64*1024*64*1024*4 байт (я специально преобразовал, что бы легко было считать) 64*1024*64*1024*4 == 1024*1024 * (32*32) * 2 * 2 * 4 = 16 Гигабайт!!! Упс. Даже если захочется 32767 на 32767, то это 4 Гигабайта. На 32битных машинах так просто такую память (да ещё и одним куском) получить. На 64 битных можно, но сложнее (если оперативки не хватает, то оно в своп свалится)

В любом случае, сделать больше 65535 на 65535 не получится - в формате [jpg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) под ширину-высоту отведено два байта.

Comment: Уточню, что есть способ создавать jpeg (bmp, png, tiff и т.д.) не в памяти, а сразу на диске. Для этого в графических библиотеках (которые в основном написаны на Си) существуют специальные построчные (*scanline*) методы записи.

Comment: Версию  Zed подтверждаю, натыкался на такие библиотеки, но ни документации, ни примеров. Google не помог. И опять таки, фотошоп работает с такими изображениями, и довольно легко. p.s. Оперативкой запасся заранее.

Comment: @Demi Это не версия. Я это из личного опыта говорю. Программа, которая собирается из сорцов по линку, что я давал в комментариях к вопросу, умеет все эти форматы создавать сразу на диске. Покопайтесь в сорцах хорошенько. Что касается документации и примеров, то их на самом деле полно. Но оно всё на английском и по большому счёту для Си.

Comment: Вполне возможно обработать такое изображение и даже сохранить его на диск (даже если памяти ну совсем в обрез) - просто придется очень аккуратно обрабатывать данные.Но вот думаю даже фотошоп не сможет сохранить jpeg больше 65535 на 65535

Comment: @KoVadim Так если формат такого разрешения не допускает, тут уже никто не сможет сохранить. Тут и думать нечего.

Comment: [Фотошоп успешно создал и сохранил.](https://yadi.sk/i/qSfKCxs43TMPuA)

Comment: больше 65535 на 65535 ? в любом случае ссылка не доступна